# Making comparisons between Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I know I have read a way to do what I am looking for but I can't seem to find it.

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
       Chrom        Loc WT Var Change ConvChange  AO     DP          VAF  \
0       chr1  115227855  T   A    T>A        T>A   5  19346  0.000258451   

      IntEx   Gene Upstream Downstream Individual  
0      TIII  TIIIa        T          C          1
```

I would like to understand across `Individual` where the greatest differences in `VAF` exist at each unique `Chrom`, `Loc` and `Change` combination.

I was thinking of changing the current DataFrame so it looks something like below to give me standard deviation column that could be sorted to give me the locations with the greatest differences. Is this a good approach and is there a good way to do something like this?

```
                                1              2              3           Mean             Std
chr1-115227855-T>A    0.000258451    0.000548128    0.000789456    0.000532011    0.0002170812
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example but contains the property you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some Pandas reshaping:

MCVE:

Given:

```
print(df)

  Chrom  Individual       VAF Var WT
0  chr1           1  0.076397   A  T
1  chr1           2  0.964344   A  T
2  chr1           3  0.563713   A  T
```

Reshape and aggregate:

```
df.set_index(['Chrom','WT','Var','Individual'])['VAF'].unstack(-1)\
  .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(mean=x.mean(1), std=x.std(1)))
```

Output:

```
Individual           1         2         3      mean       std
Chrom WT Var                                                  
chr1  T  A    0.076397  0.964344  0.563713  0.534818  0.444678
```

Comment: This looks like what I was hoping for, but it throws an error that `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. But everything should be unique and `np.where(df.index.duplicated())` seems to confirm this. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TheNightman   In this example if you have duplicate records with ['Chrom', 'WT', 'Var', 'Individual'] exactly the same, then this will cause ths error, then you have to choose how you want to aggregate 'VAF'.  I suspect that in your dataset, You don't just have one record per the forementioned columns.  If this is the case, then we cannot use the unstack method as is.